# add a tag by another user by using acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

By using `acts-as-taggable-on`, I made possible to add tags to a `word` model. And each word belongs to a `user`.

And I want to make it possible another user can add a tag but for a given amount of time after adding a tag the user can't add another tag.

To implement the function I'm stuck at a error `params not found: word`.

I rewrite a form

```
<%= form_for [word.user, word] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  <%= f.submit 'Edit' %>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag add_tag_user_word_path(word.user, word) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :tag %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
<% end %>
```

then I got the `params not found` error, when I submit the form.

I could not find the way to pass `params[:word]` by using `form_tag`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can write like `"word[tag]"` like this.

```
<%= form_tag add_tag_user_word_path(word.user, word) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "word[tag]" %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
<% end %>
```

Then it works as I hope.